# Less ugly way to encode HTML with jQuery on the fly?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to HTML-encode the insides of all `<code>` elements using jQuery, but the best I could come up with from reading the internet was this ugly solution:

> `$code = $('code');`
>   `$code.html($code.text($code.html()).html());`

It works great, but is there a less ugly solution for this?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you want to do. Can you give us a "before and after"? In particular, if a character is not messing up your HTML, it is not important to encode it. If it is, it is already too late.

Comment: ugly is a subjective thing...what is the problem?

Comment: It seems like the first `$code.html(` and the last `.html())` would cancel each other out; you're just doing `$code.text($code.html())`.

Comment: @Amadan Before, it starts with `<code><p>Hello, world!</p></code>`. After, jQuery encodes it to `<code>&lt;p&gt;Hello, world!&lt;/p&gt;</code>`. Since escaping each < and > is tedious, it would be great to have a script do it for you.

Comment: Cheers[.](http://stackoverflow.com) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeremy Banks helped me with his comment,

> It seems like the first `$code.html(` and the last `.html())` would cancel each other out; you're just doing `$code.text($code.html())`.